# Enable .APK download from QR scan

Tags: android, apk, qr-code, samsung-mobile

this is probably an easy solution but I am coming up dry.  We have published various .apk files on our own webserver.  Using Samsung 9 and 10e, we have allowed permission to install from an unknown source.  If I navigate directly to the url, example:  http://[mywebserverip].com/apk/[someapk].apk, then the device will download the apk and with permission with install it.  But, if I generate a QR code, say from https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/, with the above URL, then scan with the same device, it will detect the correct url, try to push to Chrome, but nothing downloads from there.

I have checked Camera permissions, installed 3rd party QR code reader, etc.. same result.  Any idea of what is causing this to fail?

Thanks!!

Comment: No help here? I have the same issue